# To include a variable in the ode45 syntax and tp plot coupled equation vs that variable

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, 2d, equation

In the following program code, i need to plot ABS[`B(1)`] or ABS[`B(2)`] versus `delk`. I am not knowing how to access `B(1)` in the function calling part of the code. Please give a hint to get out of this problem.

Comment: First of all, I think you are already capable of accessing `B`, aren't you? I mean `B` is an output of *ode* solver. Second, you are already calculating `delk` in the function, why do you need it to introduce when you call the function? Accesing the `delk` for workspace might be needed then you can define it as *global* variable..

Comment: Hii mehmet, In my case delk is not a scalar but a vector quantity.
So,i am unable to run the code since the ode is dependent on two variables(Z1 and delk).
syntax for ode45 treats only one variable. 
Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Hi to you.. Then, you can define `delk` and try `[Z1, B] = ode45(@(t, x)DFG789(t, x, delk),[0 3], [(0.1) 0 1]);`

Comment: yeah,i tried the same syntax but landing up in few errors and am stuck in that.